# Return a list variable from a helm helper function

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I would like to save some boilerplate template code in helm.
In my values.yaml I have to fields: `schema`, `schemas` which define the same object, once singular and once as list.

In my template I would like to not care about this. Thats why I combine this field as a single list:

```
{{- $schemas := list -}}
{{- if .Values.schema -}}
{{- $schemas = list .Values.schema -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- if .Values.schemas -}}
{{- $schemas = .Values.schemas -}}
{{- end -}}
```

then I can simply loop over `$schemas`

Now I do not want to copy past this whole bulk into every template. I would love to handle this as a helper function.

so I tried this:

```
{{- define "helper.schemas" -}}
{{- $schemas := list -}}
{{- if .Values.postgres.database.schema -}}
{{- $schemas = list .Values.postgres.database.schema -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- if .Values.postgres.database.schemas -}}
{{- $schemas = .Values.postgres.database.schemas -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- $schemas }}
{{- end -}}

.....
mytemplate.yaml

{{- range $indx, $schema := include "helper.schemas" .  }}
...
```

this results in `range can't iterate over [map[.. ..]]`

How can I pass as helm list from a helper function to a template variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Go `text/template` language, `define`d helper functions only ever produce strings.  In the core language, the `template` action writes the string to the template's output; Helm has an `include` extension that returns a string, but it always returns only a string and nothing else.

In principle you could use some other syntax, like transforming the list result to and from JSON

```
{{- define "helper.schemas -}}
{{/* ... */}}
{{- toJson $schemas -}}
{{- end -}}

{{ $schemas := include "helper.schemas" . | fromJson }}
```

Perhaps writing this as a one-liner might make it easier to copy-and-paste, but maybe not

```
{{ $schemas := .Values.schema | list | compact | default .Values.schemas }}
```

(Take `schema`; package it into a singleton list; remove falsey [null] values from the list; and if the result is falsey [empty] then use `schemas` instead.)

In practice I'd probably avoid having two different settings for the same thing and just use the list-typed `schemas` setting, with the YAML syntax for a single-valued list being pretty straightforward.

Comment: I've seen your suggestion with  `toJson/fromJson` but was hoping for something else :) And I actually really like this one liner! Thank you very much